# Loading and deleting images on the server with a preview in browser

Tags: javascript, php

I have an advertising site, the idea is simple: in your account you can upload and delete multiple images by previewing them in a browser before send it to the server. When clicking save button all the data is sent to the server. Then, to be able either remove or add new image, load these by cycle (on PHP, while load HTML page) and then placed in an array (JavaScript), later reveal whether any changes in relation to images, if there are new photos - just send them to the server, or delete any on server.

The problem is that the images are not placed in an array in the order in which they appear on HTML page. The exact code works on every boot in different ways, sometimes the same as the order of images, sometimes not. It may be the case in the difference of the speed of loading of each image, but we load them into the array after the page has fully loaded.

Below is the code.

**Loading images:**

```
<?php 
  $imgOut = '';
  $i = 0;
  while( ($fileName = $fileNamesArr->fetch_object()) !== null ){ //Image names from the database

   $imgOut .= '<div id="img-'.$i.'" class="image" style="background: url(images/'.$fileName->Filename.'); background-size: cover;">';
    $imgOut .= '<a href="#" id="drop-'.$i.'" class="drop-button">Удалить изображение</a>';
   $imgOut .= '</div>';
   $i++;
  } 

  echo '<div id="upload-button"><span>Кол-во файлов: <b>'.$i.'</b></span></div>'.$imgOut;
  ?>
```

**Then push it in array:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $(window).load(function() {
        var dataArray = [];
   var data_Array_old = [];
           var divImg = $('.image');
           var re = /^url\("(.+)"\)$/;

       $.each(divImg, function(index){
           var str = $(this).css('background-image');
         //alert(str);

        var newstr = str.replace(re, "$1");
         (function(index){
           var img = new Image();

        img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        img.onload = function () {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
             canvas.width = this.width;
            canvas.height = this.height;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
             dataArray.push({name : newstr.replace(/(.+)\/(\w+)\.(jpg|jpeg)$/,"$2"), value : dataURL});
           //alert(dataArray[index].name);
               if((index + 1) == divImg.length) {
                 Array.prototype.push.apply(data_Array_old, dataArray)
               }
        };

        img.src = newstr;
        })(index); 

      }); 
    });
--></script>
```

If we uncomment alerts, we can get some like that: alert1 - img1, img2, img3 then alert2 - error(Cannot read property 'name' of undefined), img2, img3. So, dataArray will contain only two images, img1 not pushed, but in next boot it can pushed successfully.

Comment: I see the problem but I didn't understand what exactly is your question and whether the solution should be done in php or in javascript.

Comment: In PHP **if** you can get an array of newly uploaded images and an array of existing images (initially uploaded), you can use `array_intersect` and `array_diff` to find new ones.

Comment: The code alignment on equal signs looks terrible and the your example does not convince me, that you really need the javascript at all, because PHP could have created the canvas as well. The ordering thing might also be a result of this over engineered approach, because it creates a new canvas element each time, where it should reuse the container, which was already there (or delete and recreate it). Where is that code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a form and append / remove elements inside the form ...
Then submit this form via post and process the form serverside.

Beforehand you can make a call, to get all image urls from your server.
The server then may store these somewhere temporarily if desired only on session scope or sth.

You use these as media url inside your html, with checkboxes ... That way your html manages your **state** already. 
The

```
 <form action="yourservice.php" method="post" target="_blank"/>
```

makes the submission automatically a nice request body.
You can use it with

```
<fieldset/>, <input type="radio,checkbox"> , ....
```

And in JS , to escape the strings you should generally use

```
encodeURI() // to escape your strings
```